# ImportError: cannot import name 'url' from 'django.conf.urls' django-rest-auth

Tags: django, url, django-rest-framework, importerror, django-rest-auth

error :  from django.conf.urls import url
ImportError: cannot import name 'url' from 'django.conf.urls'

-version
Django==4.0.1
django-rest-auth==0.9.5

```
Pl help me.Thank you in advance
```

url.py

```
# Core Django imports
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.urls import re_path,include
# from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.conf import settings
# Rest framework imports
from rest_framework import permissions

# Simple JWT imports
from drf_yasg.views import get_schema_view
from drf_yasg import openapi

schema_view = get_schema_view(
    openapi.Info(
        title="Heathy Living Guide API",
        default_version='v1',
        description="Heathy Living Guide",
    ),
    public=True,
    permission_classes=(permissions.AllowAny,),
)

urlpatterns = (
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/authentication/', include('apps.authentication.urls'),authentication'),
    path('api/users/', include('apps.users.urls'), name='users'),
    path('rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    # re_path(r'^rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls'))
)

urlpatterns += [
    path('api/swagger/', schema_view.with_ui('swagger', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-swagger-ui'),
    path('api/redoc/', schema_view.with_ui('redoc', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-redoc')
]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

django-rest-auth is not supporting django 4.0. `django-rest-auth` looks abandoned, last commit was 3 years ago.

Answer (score 10):

According to the [drf documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#django-rest-auth-dj-rest-auth):

> Django-rest-auth is the original project, but is not currently
> receiving updates.
>
> [Dj-rest-auth](https://github.com/iMerica/dj-rest-auth) is a newer fork of the project.

If you still want to use django-rest-auth, there are several deprecated calls to the API which you need to replace:

- For django.conf.urls use

  from django.urls import re_path as url
- For ugettext use

  from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
- for force_text use

  from django.utils.encoding import force_str as force_text

[source](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/issues/650#issuecomment-1004764059)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `from django.conf.urls import url` with `from django.urls import re_path`.

```py
urlpatterns = (
    re_path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path('api/authentication/', include('apps.authentication.urls'),authentication),
    re_path('api/users/', include('apps.users.urls'), name='users'),
    re_path('rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    # re_path(r'^rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls'))
)
```

Comment: Please use code sample format to make your answer more readable